# How object referencing works in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript and I thought objects are passed by reference.

The output I expected was:

```
{ one: 1 } { one: 1 }
{ two: 2 } { two: 2 }
```

Output obtained:

```
{ one: 1 } { one: 1 }
{ two: 2 } { one: 1 }
```

When `b` is referencing address of `a`, why is `b` still `{ one: 1 }`

```js
var a = {one:1}
var b = a

console.log(a,b)

a = {two:2}

console.log(a,b)
```

Comment: `a = whatever` doesn't affect `b` in any way.

Comment: @emix not a console logging synchronicity issue at all

Comment: This really doesn't have to do with pass-by-reference either, since there is no passing involved in this question, but the duplicate explains this behavior anyway.

Comment: In js you cannot have object value. You always have object referens. So you actually passing references by value.

Answer (score 5):

when you did `b = a`, so now the `b` holds the same reference as of `a`

But when you assign a new value to `a`

```
a = { one : 2 }
```

It created a new memory reference for the value ( `{ one : 2 }` ) and tag it with `a` variable, so you can refer to the memory reference using `a` and get the value. but `b` still holds the initial reference of `a` which has value `{one : 1}`

Answer (score 1):

Let's analyze this one by one:

```
var a = { one: 1 }  // 'a' points now to (example) location: #fff
var b = a        // 'b' points to the same location: #fff
```

Now, when you are asigning a new object to `a`:

```
a = { two: 2 }
```

`a` now points to **new** location in memory (say, `#ff1`) and it doesn't affect `b`'s location, which **still points to `#fff`**. That is why the last `console.log(a,b)` call gives you `{ two: 2 } { one: 1 }` output.

Answer (score 1):

> When `b` is referencing address of `a`, why is `b` still `{ one: 1 }`

Because `b` is not referencing the address of `a`, but both of them are referencing the address of object `{ one: 1 }`. Then `a` starts referencing the address of a brand new, different object, `{ two: 2 }`, and absolutely nothing changes about `b`, or the first object, `{ one: 1 }`, which still remains intact and existing, exactly because `b` needs it.