# typescript map.get() returns undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript

I know this is a repetitive question, but I've gone through the other questions and tried the solutions posted there but couldn't get it to work.
Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0rn6fh5w/8/).
My key is a little complicated and I can't change it so I'm stuck.

```
const testMap = new Map<newObject, Array<newObject> | null>([
  [{key:'mainKey', value:'mainValue'}, null]
]);

console.log(testMap.get({key:'mainKey', value:'mainValue'}))
```

The value of null will be replaced by an array of objects same type as the key.

Also, I tried initializing the map and then added objects using set but that didn't work either.

Comment: You can't `get` with an object of the same shape, you need to use a reference to the same obect the key was set with. see: [Map: Key equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#key_equality)

Comment: “can’t change it” how? Can you describe what this is going to be used for? (You can’t look up objects by property equality in a `Map`, so there needs to be *some* kind of change.)

Comment: @pilchard what do you mean by 'reference to the same object the key was set with'?

Comment: @Ry- I need to make use of objects as a key value pair to hold my data. and one object is linked to multiple objects at once - something like 
fruit :edible = { apple:red, banana:yellow, ...}
and then like food:edible = {fruit:edible, vegetable:edible, ...}
not sure if that makes sense tbh

Comment: see: [How object referencing works in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57836242/how-object-referencing-works-in-javascript). An example for your case would be:`const o = {foo: 'bar'}; const m = new Map([[o, 'value']]); m.get(o);` where `o` stores a *reference* to an obj and the Map stores a *reference* to the same object as a key.

Comment: @pilchard This does help, but does that mean that I'll have to set the elements in the map, and I can't initialize it altogether?

Comment: No, as you see in my example I've passed `o` as the key in an entries array. But you *will* have to store a reference to each object you use as a key if you ever want to access the Map.

Comment: Okay, I think I get it and understand what the problem is. Thanks a lot!!